# Is there any attribute which has same for the "getActiveApplication()" in "HtmlService" at spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This question concern about "Warning: The UI service was deprecated on December 11, 2014. To create user interfaces, use the HTML service instead" from the Google Spreadsheet. And then to make me I chouldn't use this tag "**UiApp.getActiveApplication().close()**" & "**return UiApp.getActiveApplication()**" anymore. What the attribute /code /script has same for that both function instead is ?  I actually at least I can improvisation coding & transformation from "UiApp" changes writting to "HtmlService" of tag. Like the especially sample what I'd gave to you on this below which is I want to transform it all to HtmlService tag each of lines :

NB: I have to apologies for my english.

```
function showListSheet() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = s.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sss = ss.getSheets();
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("S h e e t L i s t . . .").setHeight(390).setWidth(200);
  var table = app.createFlexTable().setCellPadding(5).setCellSpacing(0); 
  var widgets = []; 
  for (var i = 0; i < sss.length; i++) { 
    var sheet_name = sss[i].getName(); 
    widgets[i] = app.createHTML(sheet_name).setId(sheet_name); 
    table.setWidget(i, 1, widgets[i]) 
  } 
  var panel = app.createSimplePanel(); 
  panel.add(table); 
  app.add(panel); 
  ss.show(app); 
}
```

Comment: You should probably replace that code with the HtmlService.

Comment: There is no point in looking for the equivalent of just these two lines of code - the entire UiApp service has been deprecated and replace by the [HTML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html) and there is no equivalent for those lines. You need to recode - the [HML Service Guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html) might give you a starting point.

Comment: Can I change with this I mentioned code?
-  google.script.host.close();
-  return google.script.host;

Comment: I couldn't say without seeing the whole script (which really you should provide as well as share a copy of your spreadsheet). BUT... why not give it a go and find out?

Comment: You can start by following the advice @Tedinoz gave you. And if you cannot accomplish whatever it is that you want to do, you should provide some more information for people to understand your issue and help you. Again, the script and a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on would be extremely useful.

Comment: All those methods are deprecated and currently there is no information about them in the official documentation. How did you come up with this script? Unfortunately, I cannot understand what you want to do if you don't explain it somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TADAAA !!!   Aloha ..  I think I've just resolved my own question but guess the another problem is come up to me again.  ftttt ...   is there somebody want to help me !  I just want to make multiple selected rows now implemented it into the table I'd just made with the HtmlService. Here's the code I'd made :

NB :  Excuseme about my english wrote.

```
function showListSheet() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = s.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sss = ss.getSheets();
  var result = "<head><style type='text/css'>.gridview {display: inline-block; border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0px 4px 4px 0; box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #bbb;} .gridview, .gridview td,  .gridview th {margin: 0; border:  1px solid #cccccc;} .gridview th {font-size: 1.1em; height: 25px; text-align: center; font-weight: normal; color: #F9F9F9; background: #337EB5;} .gridview th a, .gridview th a:link, .gridview th a:visited, .gridview th a:active {color: #F9F9F9; text-decoration: none;} .gridview th a:hover {text-decoration: underline;} .gridview tr {background: #F4F9FD;} .gridview tr:nth-child(odd)  {background-color: #F4F9FD;} .gridview tr:nth-child(even)  {background-color: #EDF5FC;} .gridview td  {font-weight: normal; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;} .gridview td {padding: 4px 0 5px 9px;} .gridview tfoot td {background-color: #EEEEEE;} .gridview tfoot td .page {color: #000000; font-weight: bold;} .gridview tr.subfoot, .gridview tr.subfoot td {background-color: #FFFFEC;} .gridview tr:hover td, .gridview tbody tr:hover td {background-color: #feb4cc; cursor: pointer; color: white;} .gridview .selected, .gridview tbody .selected {background-color: #E74C3C;  -webkit-animation: miniRainBow 20s infinite;  animation: miniRainBow 20s infinite; color: #fff;}</style></head><table border=1 class='gridview'>";
    for (var i = 0; i < sss.length; i++) {
        result += "<tr OnClick=\"this.id.attr('class', 'selected')\" id=\"tgt\">"
          result += "<td><input type='checkbox' onClick='return false;' readonly/></td><td>" + sss[i].getName() + "</td>";
      result += "</tr>";
    }
    result += "</table>";

  ss.show(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(result)
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    .setTitle("L i s t   O f   S h e e t   . . .")
    .setHeight(500)
    .setWidth(300));
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I just don't understand what you are trying to accomplish now. Could you expand on that? Also, for documentation purposes, if your original question was solved, and if you want people to help you, maybe you should post your new problem in another question and mark this one as solved by accepting your own answer.